# sync "start time" between two microservices

Tags: time, microservices

consider service A (consumer) and service B (server).
They will start streaming process (e.g gRPC) - A will send data, B will process and retrieve.

Thing is there is need some time agreement between them within the messages (e.g. elasped time from start connection). As each of them need to sync on that.

What would be a good way to make A and B be on the same time?

Answer (score 2):

Agreement on time between remote agents in a distributed system is an *extremely* tricky problem. Spanner went to [great lengths](https://storage.googleapis.com/pub-tools-public-publication-data/pdf/45855.pdf) to ensure accurate synchronization.

Fortunately, this is mostly a solved problem (when extreme precision isn't required). Syncing up all of your nodes with [NTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5905) and then sending a timestamp in the initial request should suffice. If your NTP server is on the public internet, this should get you accuracy down to the order of tens of milliseconds. If the NTP server (and all clients) are on the same LAN, you can expect a higher degree of precision.